# I uninstalled Java 1.5 but it still shows in Control Panel, and in Program Files directory?

Tags: java, uninstall

I have uninstalled Java using the `Control Panel > Uninstall or Change a program`  However I still see the `Java` option in the Control Panel and I still have directory `c:\Program Files\Java\`

I can also still open a command prompt and run `c:\java -version` and get the old version.

I have tried using the `http://java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp` but it believes I do not have Java still installed and will not launch the uninstaller applet.

How can I really remove `Java 1.5` from my PC so I can install `Java 1.7` cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

Java on Windows can be installed in any directory, and you can have many different versions installed at the same time. I remember that OpenOffice had an option to include Java with the download. If you didn't have Java installed, it did so for you, in its own directory, and it was kept there independent of any other Java install.

You can download a zipped version of Java, unzip it in `C:\java or C:\java-123` and run it from there. You probably removed Java from `C:\Program Files\Java`. You can rename or zip the `C:\Java` folder and see what program starts to complain, then decide to move it back.

You can go ahead and install Java 1.7. It will install cleanly. The only thing that might pose a problem is the `$JAVA_HOME` system variable. You can [change those manually](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/11/29/set-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-java/) if needed. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673871/setting-up-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-java-and-ant) for another howto!